# Как сделать выборку только тех объектов, у которых есть связанные объекты

Tags: python, django

Есть 2 модели со связью ForeignKey

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='child', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Как сделать выборку только тех родителей, у которых есть хотя бы один ребенок?

```py
qs = Parent.objects.filter(child='как это сделать?')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел

```py
qs = Parent.objects.filter(child__isnull=False).distinct()
```